# onChange effect after second entry

Tags: reactjs, onchange

I'm a bit new with ReactJS and I have a problem with my `onChange` function, it starts displaying after the second entry and it is one letter late every time. And I clearly don't understand why

Here is my code:

```
const [values, setValues] = useState({
    latinName: "",
    wingLength: "",
    weight: "",
    adiposity: "",
    age: "",
    howCaptured: "",
    whenCaptured: "",
    whereCaptured: "",
    ringNumber: "",
    takeover: "",
});

const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;

    setValues({
        ...values,
        [name]: value,
    });

    console.log(values);
}

<input type="text" name="latinName" id="latinName" onChange={handleChange} value={values.latinName} />
```

[Here my input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5XAbU.png)

[Here my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/igM1A.png)

Comment: `setState` is async ,so you see the previous value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`useState` hook's `setState` works `async`. As a result, during state update, you are still getting the previous value in the mean time.

You can use `useEffect` hook in your case.

`useEffect(() => console.log(values), [values]);`

Full code:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [values, setValues] = useState({
    latinName: "",
    wingLength: "",
    weight: "",
    adiposity: "",
    age: "",
    howCaptured: "",
    whenCaptured: "",
    whereCaptured: "",
    ringNumber: "",
    takeover: ""
  });

  useEffect(() => console.log(values), [values]);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;

    setValues({
      ...values,
      [name]: value
    });
  };

  return (
    <input
      type="text"
      name="latinName"
      id="latinName"
      onChange={handleChange}
      value={values.latinName}
    />
  );
}
```

[CodeSandBox Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-ramanujan-5og81?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Perfect it works, I understand a little better how it works! Thanks :)

Comment: You r welcome 